# Access variable outside a foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, razor

How do I go about accessing a variable outside a loop? The code below doesn't seem to work, the variable is empty.

```
var userID;
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT ProviderUserId FROM webpages_OAuthMembership WHERE UserID = @0", currentUserId))
{
    userID = row.ProviderUserId;

}  
var userID1 = userID;
```

Comment: How does `var userID;` even compile?

Comment: The code works, the last value userID is assigned to is empty.

Comment: If I replace the query with a string array it doesn't compile on my machine?

Comment: @levib: Maybe the OP has a type called `var`. Probably not, but they *could*...

Comment: Empty result of db.Query so that userID assignment never executes?

Comment: userID should be flagged as potentially unassigned. This shouldn't compile.

Comment: Yeah Query was empty. It's sorted out now. And initially I meant `var userID = ""` Thanks guys

Comment: What's wrong with 'string' nowadays? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Which iteration do you want the value from? The first? The last? What should happen if there are no results?

LINQ is probably a simpler approach here:

```
string sql = "SELECT ProviderUserId FROM webpages_OAuthMembership WHERE UserID = @0";
var userId = db.Query(sql, currentUserId)
               .Select(x => x.ProviderUserId)
               .SingleOrDefault();
if (userId != null)
{
    ...
}
```

(Of course that won't work as-is if `ProviderUserId` isn't a nullable type of some kind, but we don't really have much information at the moment...)

Answer (score 0):

your foreach loop return `IEnumerable` collection

```
var userID;
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT ProviderUserId FROM webpages_OAuthMembership WHERE UserID = @0", currentUserId))
{
    userID = row.ProviderUserId;

}  
var userID1 = userID;
```

for holding `userID` you can do this

```
List<string> userIDs = new List<string>();
foreach(var row in db.Query("SELECT ProviderUserId FROM webpages_OAuthMembership WHERE UserID = @0", currentUserId))
{
    userIDs.Add( row.ProviderUserId);

}  
//Now You have items in userIDs List
```